# Facebook iOS SDK - redundant "OK" click during second login?

Tags: ios, facebook

I'm using FB iOS SDK for authenticating users. And this is how FB application looks during second login (after user logged in, gave all permissions then logged out, then logged in again):

[image: Facebook iOS - second login]

Which seems a little bit excess since user already gave all permissions.

And in some applications this process (second login) looks as follows:

1)User clicks "login"

2)There's a brief switch between current app and FB application

3)Then OS switches back, without need to press "OK" button

Is there any way to implement or force this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem solved by adding iOS Bundle ID at facebook application profile (go to https://developers.facebook.com/apps/ then choose your app -> edit settings -> iOS application)

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the session after logging in and restore it the next time.
Here's a quick how-to: http://coffeeshopped.com/2011/01/saving-sessions-with-the-facebook-ios-sdk

This way, the user doesn't have to log in as long as the token doesn't expire (which is in the far far future)